# Make exceptions inside a change function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, stoppropagation

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$('#invitation_emails').on('change', function () {
  var tagsArray = $('#invitation_emails')[0].selectize.items;
  var lastItem = tagsArray[tagsArray.length - 1];
  var emailHelpBlock = $($('.invitation').find('.help-block')[0])
  if (!isEmail(lastItem) && !_.isUndefined(lastItem)) {
    $('#invitation_emails')[0].selectize.removeItem(lastItem);
    if (emailHelpBlock.is(":hidden")) {
      emailHelpBlock.show( 'slide', { direction: 'down'});
     }
   } else {
     emailHelpBlock.hide( 'slide', { direction: 'up'});
   }
});
```

Given an array of tags, it checks if the content of a tag is a valid email address. If not, the code removes the tag and should show a help message ONLY if such message is hidden. If the next attempt is an invalid address again the message should stay visible, else it should be hidden.

With this code the message, however, is not displayed correctly in all scenarios. The problem is that when an email is not valid the function removes a tag with the line:

```
$('#invitation_emails')[0].selectize.removeItem(lastItem);
```

and this is undesirably regarded as a change. Therefore the function runs again checks the validity of the previous tag, if exists, and shows or hides the message accordingly.

I'd like the function to ignore the change that happens as a result of the removed tag but I can't wrap my head around how to do it. I've tried building a function like:

```
function remove_tag(e) {
 $('#invitation_emails')[0].selectize.removeItem(lastItem);
 e.stopPropagation();
}
```

and executing it instead of the line that removes the tag alone. Don't seem to work out how to use this technique for this purposes though. Any advice?

Comment: snippet! snippet! snippet!

Comment: so you wan tyour code to run only when tag is ADDED instead of REMOVED?

Comment: @Scaramouche you got me in the middle of the snippet! It'll take me more than I thought. Yes actually that'd be the case. Thinking on it like that it may be easier if I double check the Selectizer and see if they have events that I can use for this

Comment: I have never used selectize.js but I found [this page](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/examples/events.html) which might help, notice `onItemAdd`/`onItemRemove`

Comment: @Scaramouche getting late in here!! I'll give it a look should be easier this way. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Scaramouche done. Much easier. Thanks for reminding me the importance of reading the documentation before doing anything custom made. It could have saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Scaramouche suggested much easier to look for an already available event handler in Selectize plugin. The validation is now performed only when an item is added without causing unexpected issues.

```
    $('#invitation_emails').selectize({
        plugins: ['remove_button'],
        delimiter: ',',
        persist: false,
        create: function(input) {
                return {
                        value: input,
                        text: input
                }
        },
        onItemAdd: function(e){
            var itemText = e;
            var emailHelpBlock = $($('.invitation').find('.help-block')[0]);
            if (!isEmail(itemText) && !_.isUndefined(itemText)) {
                $('#invitation_emails')[0].selectize.removeItem(itemText);
                if (emailHelpBlock.is(":hidden")) {
                    emailHelpBlock.show( 'slide', { direction: 'down'});
                }
            } else {
                emailHelpBlock.hide( 'slide', { direction: 'up'});
            }
        },
    });
```